# Angularjs print text not working based on ng-switch

Tags: angularjs

Here is my current [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/8JZadWW1lEbUiXBVK6zs?p=preview).

What I am trying to do is to: generate different content after click each dropdown toggle.
For example, when text is clicked, "Text" shows under the button.

Could someone help me on that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the ng-model from the **li** element & add a ng-click handler to your **a** tag. This way you can use the choice that you selected for whatever you want to do with it.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/oTHWf2I266SHjur5Ebv8?p=preview

**HTML:**

```
<!-- ADD ITEM BUTTON -->
      <li class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Add item</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
            <a ng-click="selectItem(choice)">{{choice.type}}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

      {{selection}}
```

**JS:**

```
$scope.selection = {};

    $scope.selectItem = function(choice) {
      $scope.selection = choice;
    }
```